# jQuery move each img tag into each a elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move each img tag from div into each a tag any ideas? Thanks!

```
<div><img src="imga.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="imgb.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="imgc.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="imgd.jpg" /></div>

<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
```

so the result shoud look like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="imga.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="imgb.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="imgc.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="imgd.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: [what code did you use when you tried to solve this problem?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Do the href tags already exist? Otherwise you can consider the `wrap()`: [jQuery-wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve the problem, but you will have to improve the selectors so that other elements will not get affected by this

```
var $imgs = $('div > img').unwrap();
$('a').each(function(i){
    $(this).append($imgs[i]);
})
```

Comment: diz worked perfectlii, danke !